# Infinite for loop in React using timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I do have this function that print values of `urls` array, the first thing I want to do is run the forloop indefinitely and the second thing I don't understand why the 'done' console log is executed before the for loop:

```
loop = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            (function(index) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log(urls[index]);
                }, i * 1000);
            })(i);
        }
        console.log('done');        
};
```

I tried wrapping this function inside another forloop but I got (in this example) 3 values each time, which is not my goal, I just need to repeat the loop.

```
for (var a = 1; a <= 3; a++) {
  setTimeout(() => this.loop(), 21000);
}

// Not working ( the urls.length = 21 so that's exactly 21 seconds )

while (true) {
  setTimeout(() => this.loop(), 21000);
}

// Freeze too much ram
```

Please someone suggest a better approach or help m solve the logic behind this

Comment: It might be worth looking into [how JavaScript handles asynchronous logic](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript).

Comment: If you want something to run indefinitely, why not use `setInterval`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` with correct timeout solve the issue:

```
loop = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            (function(index) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.setState({ img: urls[index] });
                }, i * 500);
            })(i);
        }
};

svg = e => {
    this.setState({ anim: true, form: true });
     this.loop();
        setInterval(() => this.loop(), 10000);
};
```

> urls.length = 20

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` doesn't block, it basically schedule the log call for `i` seconds in the future, that's why the "done" message is printed because all the scheduling has been finished, not the actually print url call.

I don't really understand what you want to do but I guess this is pretty close:

```
const printUrl = j => {
  console.log(urls[j])
  setTimeout(() => printUrl(j + 1), j * 1000)
}
printUrl(1)
```

Comment: oh boy, let's say I have an array with a,b,c I'd like to print values x infinite times